# Highlight cells that contain Non-English Characters

Tags: google-sheets

I need to highlight cells that contain non-English characters. I tried the following regex:

```
=len(trim(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[A-Za-z0-9]", "")))
```

but it matches hyphens and slashes, etc.

I'm interested in using the =DETECTLANGUAGE function in Google Sheets, but I don't know where to start in regards to implementing the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
=len(trim(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[[:punct:]]",""),"[[:alnum:]]","")))
```

[image]

[You can find an example here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HOSbGcv49ISf5nyuFzAHOYZk8q5u3sP_mlkNOnUrCaU/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `DetectLanguage` would do what you want. As [this documentation shows](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093278?hl=en), `DetectLanguage` returns the two letter language code, but English characters could return other languages.

Example `=DETECTLANGUAGE("Bonjour")` returns `fr` (French) even though all English characters.

I think the below formulas are the way to go, which werent too far from what you were doing. Each will return a `TRUE` value if anything other than items specified in the RegEx is identified.

Just letters, numbers and white spaces (`\s`):

```
=len(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[A-Za-z0-9\s]",""))>0
```

Previous test but takes into account `.` `,` `?` `!`

```
=len(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[A-Za-z\.?!,0-9\s]",""))>0
```

[Here's a sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ekEf6pvz63NGD0M6kTgGYoF-Vbr3yli54IqOVRKszpE/edit?usp=sharing) along with some other Regex Stuff (see the tab with your question number).